# Solving maze with Backtracking

Tags: scala, backtracking, maze

I am trying to solve a maze with scala using backtracking.

My problem is that I keep on getting StackOverflow errors.

I have tried qite alot of things but I always end up with a StackOverflow.

findStart() and the getWay() show two approaches I have used.

I know that it is possible to do this with Streams and calculate all possible ways in one recursion but I would like to solve it with backtracking first.

Here is my Code:

```
object MazeSolver {

  case class Cell(free: Boolean, start: Boolean)

  type Maze = Seq[Seq[Cell]]

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {

    val lab = lislab("laby1.rinth")

    val entrance = findStart(lab, Position(0, 0))


   println(getWay(lab, entrance(0), entrance(0), Nil))

  }

  def findStart(lab: Maze, pos: Position): List[Position] = {
    try {
      if (lab(pos.column)(pos.row).start)
        List(pos)
      else
        findStart(lab, pos.south) ::: findStart(lab, pos.north) ::: findStart(lab, pos.west) ::: findStart(lab, pos.east)
    } catch {
      case _: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException => Nil
    }

  }

  def getWay(maze: Maze, pos: Position, lastPos: Position, way: List[Position]): List[Position] = {
    try {
      if (!maze(pos.column)(pos.row).free && !maze(pos.column)(pos.row).start) {
        Nil

      } else {

        if (isExit(pos, maze)) {
          pos :: way
        } else {

          val posList = List(pos.north, pos.south, pos.west, pos.east)

          posList.foreach { x => 
            val tail = getWay(maze, x, pos, way) 
            if(tail != Nil) tail :: way
            }


          Nil

        }
      }
    } catch { case _: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException => way }

  }

  def lislab(fn: String): Maze = {
    try {
      (for (column <- io.Source.fromFile(fn, "UTF-8").getLines.toList)
        yield for (c <- column) yield Cell(c == ' ', c == '?')).toIndexedSeq
    } catch { case _: java.io.FileNotFoundException => Nil }
  }

  case class Position(column: Int, row: Int) {
    override def toString = "(" + column + "." + row + ")"
    def north = Position(column - 1, row)
    def south = Position(column + 1, row)
    def west = Position(column, row - 1)
    def east = Position(column, row + 1)
  }

  def isExit(pos: Position, lab: Maze): Boolean = {
    val cell = lab(pos.column)(pos.row)
    cell.free && (pos.column == 0
      || pos.column == lab.length - 1
      || pos.row == 0
      || pos.row == lab(0).length - 1)

  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I make the findStart() and getWay() functions work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm only going to comment on `findStart` for now.

There are two things wrong with `findStart`:

1. `findStart` is recursively called on every adjacent cell. Unfortunately, the neighbouring cell of any neighbour is the cell itself.
2. The function never checks if you can actually walk on a given cell (I assume Cell.free means you can walk on the cell).

Let's look at an example to see why the first point leads to a StackOverflow. Assume a maze consisting of only one row of three columns:

```
[A] <-> [B] <-> [C (start)]
```

Now your algorithm starts at `A`. Since `A.start == false`, it calls `findStart(A.east)` which is `findStart(B)`. Now since `B.start == false` it calls `findStart(B.west)` and `findStart(B.east)`. The first one is the same as `findStart(A)`, leading to infinite recursion.

To fix this, you need to keep track on which cells you have already visited. One way to achieve this is by passing a list of already visited positions.

Regarding point 2, you simply need to check whether a certain position is walkable, by checking `maze(position.column)(position.row).free`.

A (not tested) implementation could look as follows:

```
def findStart2(maze: Maze, position: Position, visited: List[Position]): List[Position] =
  if (maze(position.column)(position.row).start)
    List(position) // we reached our goal
  else {
    val explorationArea: List[Position] = List(position.north, position.east, position.south, position.west) filter (x => !visited.contains(x) && canWalkOnCell(maze, x))
    // filter the adjacent positions that have already been visited or are not walkable
    explorationArea flatMap { 
      notYetVisitedPosition =>
        findStart2(maze, notYetVisitedPosition, position :: visited) // don't forget to add the current position to the list of already visited positions
    }
  }

private def canWalkOnCell(maze: Maze, position: Position): Boolean =
  indexInBound(maze, position) && maze(position.column)(position.row).free

private def indexInBound(maze: Maze, position: Position): Boolean =
  position.column >= 0 && position.row >= 0 && position.column < maze.size && position.row < maze(position.column).size
```

Comment: The findStart is to find the entrance of a maze. It will be marked with an ?. So there shouldnt be a check if the field is free I guess. 

But if I filter like this:

 `filter (x => !visited.contains(x) && indexInBound(maze, x))` I still end up in an infinte recursion.

Comment: I have now just used this method for finding the start : `def findStart2(maze: Maze, position: Position): Position = {
    for (a <- 0 until maze.length) {
      for (b <- 0 until maze(a).length) {
        if (maze(a)(b).start) return Position(a, b)
      }
    }
    Position(-1, -1)
  }`

Using your answer for the getway() function helped me to solve it. Thanks a bunch